# Magento getting "Read operation timed out" error

Tags: php, magento, redis

I am getting this error in my error log file. I am not able to find why I am getting this type of errors.

> Exception 'CredisException' with message 'Read operation timed out.' in lib/Credis/Client.php:825

Comment: See suggestions on investigation of this issue on Magento StackExchange: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130103/redis-timeout-after-a-reindex/130691

Comment: `bin/magento cache:clear`